# How to get info from HttpResponse java?

Tags: java, salesforce

First of all please look at my code below:

```
    List<BasicNameValuePair> qsList = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    qsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_token", accessToken));
    String queryString = URLEncodedUtils.format(qsList, HTTP.UTF_8);
    HttpGet userInfoRequest = new HttpGet(id + "?" + queryString);
    DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClientclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse userInfoResponse;
    try {
        userInfoResponse = defaultHttpClientclient.execute(userInfoRequest);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(userInfoResponse.getEntity());
        System.out.println("User info response: " + responseBody);
        System.out.println("");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got an access token from Salesforce. Now I request user's information via that token. In the `responseBody` I got all infomation of that user like username, id, language,... Now I need to take only username from the response. What should I do to take it?

Comment: What format is it in?

Comment: is this android? Also what format is the response? json? xml? post the response in the psot

Comment: The default response from Salesforce is json, I think.

Comment: This is not android.

Comment: @user3422401 Please post the response on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is likely in JSON. If so you can parse the data you need. I won't repost the code, instead please see: [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

```
    JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(userInfoResponse.getEntity());
    String username = responseJSON.getString("username");
```

Comment: I have done it before you edited your answer. Thank you very much.